# Total information in the universe

Tags: information

I have no business in this forum.

It seems to me the total amount of information in the universe is finite determined by pre-big bang conditins. Information is neither created or destroyed only rearranged.

How is the amount of information assigned to discrete items or systems? Is there a basic unit of measurement for determining the amount of information in say a Photon or Planetary System?

Answer (score 0):

The unit of measurement is usually created by the observation boundary of that unit. We can clearly see a "gas like" cloud in a photon and then define it, we can clearly see a solar system and the edge of a planet as well.

Comment: so would not the unit's boundary be the smallest sub-atomic particle known?